# Nomenclature errors in Lyx, don't try to define the nomenclature in a heading/subheading

Tags: nomenclature

While trying to view my document in Lyx I kept getting an error while compiling the document:

> LaTex Error: Lonely\item--perhaps a missing list environment

The descriptions stated:

```
\item [{BER}]
               \begingroup Bit Error Rate\nomeqref {42}\nompageref{16}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

By using the note feature (commenting out) on each of the nomenclature entries I found that I'd tried to define a nomenclature within a subsection title.

Commenting out the nomenclature entry allowed the document to compile and I could see my list.

Comment: This is more of a found the problem and fixed it, rather than a question. Not sure where to put it really.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

You can safely define a nomenclature entry inside a sectioning command. You just have to protect fragile commands like `\nomrefpage` and `\nomrefeq`.

For example, you can write

```
\section{Bit Error Rate (BER)\nomenclature{BER}{Bit Error Rate\protect\nomrefpage}}
```

or

```
\subsection{Meaning of $x$\nomenclature{$x$}{Unknown variable\protect\nomrefeq}}
```

and they work fine.

Also, be sure to use `\nomrefpage` and `\nomrefeq` instead of `\nompageref` and `\nomeqref` (the latter are commands used inside the `.nls` file to indicate the same things...).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature

\bigskip

\section{Bit Error Rate (BER)\nomenclature{BER}{Bit Error Rate\protect\nomrefpage}}

\begin{equation}
\textup{BER}=x
\end{equation}

\subsection{Meaning of $x$\nomenclature{$x$}{Unknown variable\protect\nomrefeq}}

$x$ is an unknown variable

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You *must* use the optional argument to `\section` and `\subsection`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\printnomenclature

\bigskip

\section
[Bit Error Rate (BER)]
{Bit Error Rate (BER)\nomenclature{BER}{Bit Error Rate\nomrefpage}}

\begin{equation}
\textup{BER}=x
\end{equation}

\subsection
[Meaning of $x$]
{Meaning of $x$\nomenclature{$x$}{Unknown variable\nomrefeq}}

$x$ is an unknown variable

\end{document}
```

Why did I say “must”? Because if you just `\protect` the fragile commands in the titles, you'll get an entry also for the appearance in the table of contents (and probably distinct from the one in the title).

However, I can't recommend adding nomenclature references in titles; it's better to have them in text.